# C# string.Contains using variable

Tags: c#, string, variables

```
string[] pullspec = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\fixedlist.txt");
foreach (string ps in pullspec)
{
    string pslower = ps.ToLower();
    string[] pslowersplit = pslower.Split('|');
    var keywords = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\crawl\keywords.txt");
    if (pslower.Contains("|"))
    {
        if (pslower.Contains(keywords))
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\" + keyword + ".txt", pslowersplit[1] + "|" + pslowersplit[0] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile because of `pslower.Contains(keywords)` but I'm not trying to do 100 foreach loops.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
if (keywords.Any(k => pslower.Contains(k)))
```

Comment: so how do i do  File.AppendAllText(@"C:\" + keyword + ".txt", pslowersplit[1] + "|" + pslowersplit[0] + "\n");

Comment: make the selected keyword the name of the text file

Comment: @Mike: Do you mean to create a file for only the first match, or for all matches?

Comment: @Mike: try this:

    var keyword = keywords.FirstOrDefault(k => pslower.Contains(k));
    if (keyword != null)
    {
        /* ... */
    }

Answer (score 2):

You have a collection of keywords, and you want to see if any of them (or all of them?) are contained in a given string. I don't see how you would solve this without using a loop somewhere, either explicit or hidden in some function or linq expression.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - create a String[]of the keywords and then `string[] parts = pslower.Split(yourStringArray, StringSplitOptions.None);` - if any of your strings appear then parts.Length > 1.  You won't easily get your hands on the keywords this way, tho'.